# Recording using CEGID application in JMeter 5.2

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

Need to record the application that is on CEGID Retail application.
Script have 8 transactions and each transaction have 100 URL that is useful in script.
We can capture request in fiddler.
can we record using Jmeter otherwise need to take requests from fiddler and put in Jmeter manually that will consume more time.

Please suggest a better approach for this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B21io.png)

after converting fiddler session to .har and .har to .jmx request body is getting removed.
Please suggest on this.

Fiddler recording you can export the captured requests in HAR format like File -> Export Sessions -> HTTP Archive 1.1 and once done you can convert them into JMeter .jmx script using online HAR to JMX conversion tool

is there any setting need to change?

Answer (score 0):

If the application is using [HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP) and/or [HTTP(S)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/https) protocols you should be able to normally record it using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder), just

1. start JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder proxy
2. import JMeter's SSL certificate into your browser, the file is called `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` and it's generated in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation
3. configure your browser to use JMeter as the proxy
4. execute your test scenario steps in browser - JMeter will store the relevant [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers under the [Recording Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Recording_Controller)

See [Recording Tests](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) user manual chapter for more details

---

If you already have a Fiddler recording you can export the captured requests in [HAR format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HAR_(file_format)) like `File -> Export Sessions -> HTTP Archive 1.1` and once done you can convert them into JMeter .jmx script using [online HAR to JMX conversion tool](https://converter.blazemeter.com/)

Comment: after coverting fiddler to .har and .har to .jmx request body is getting removed.Please suggest on this.